# Can I put store and types into core module in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, directory-structure

├── src 
│   ├── app 
│   │   ├── core 
│   │   │   ├── header 
│   │   │   │   ├── header.component.ts|css|html 
│   │   │   ├── services 
│   │   │   ├── core.module.ts 
│   │   ├── types 
│   │   │   ├── book.ts 
│   │   │   ├── student.ts 
│   │   │   ├── index.ts 
│   │   ├── store 
│   │   │   ├── books.state.ts 
│   │   │   ├── students.state.ts 
│   │   │   ├── index.ts 
│   │   ├── features 
│   │   │   ├── students 
│   │   │   │   ├── components 
│   │   │   │   ├── students-routing.module.ts 
│   │   │   │   ├── students.module.ts 
│   │   │   ├── books 
│   │   │   │   ├── components 
│   │   │   │   ├── books-routing.module.ts 
│   │   │   │   ├── books.module.ts 
│   │   ├── shared 
│   ├── app-routing.module.ts   
│   ├── app.component.css 
│   ├── app.component.html 
│   ├── app.component.ts 
│   ├── app.module.ts

I import **core.module** into **app.module**.
 **core**, **features**, **store** use **types**. and **features** use **store**. I need to know, can I put **store** folder and **types** folder into **core** folder? and use **store** and **types** through **app.module**?
I'm beginner to angular. 
thank you

Comment: Looks like they're sibling modules currently. Have you tried it (or the same operation with an example)?

Comment: I am guessing if you changed the directories without any code change, you would have issues - review the way angular code uses JS/ES imports.